# Unable to fetch job_details from Jenkins using Python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to print 'Jenkins' job details using 'jenkins api' and 'python'

I am able to print 'Jenkins version' but not 'job_details' from Jenkins

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jenkins_url = 'https://dev.localhost.com/XXXX/jenkins/'
    server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, 'user', 'password')
    print server.version
    print server.get_jobs()
```

Output

```
2.32
<generator object iteritems at 0x7f4a46220fa0>
```

Is anything wrong with my code (or) should I do something else?

Added StackTrace as suggested

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jenver.py", line 26, in <module>
    for job in jobs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jobs.py", line 91, in iteritems
    for job in self.itervalues():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jobs.py", line 116, in itervalues
    yield Job(row['url'], row['name'], self.jenkins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/job.py", line 74, in __init__
    JenkinsBase.__init__(self, self.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/job.py", line 98, in poll
    data = super(Job, self).poll(tree=tree)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 59, in poll
    data = self._poll(tree=tree)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 69, in _poll
    return self.get_data(url, tree=tree)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 79, in get_data
    response = requester.get_url(url, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi/utils/requester.py", line 109, in get_url
    return requests.get(self._update_url_scheme(url), **requestKwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='6.4.2.182', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /scm/jenkins/job/DO%20NOT%20CHANGE%20THIS%20PROJECT/api/python (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5bcf894150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

Comment: That connection error is a different issue - you cannot connect to the job for some reason. Check the host, port and URL are as you would expect or raise a different question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `get_jobs` is returning a generator rather than a list. See [example](https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_jenkinsapi.html) 2 for how to print the details of jobs.

To print the items of the generator try doing:

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

if __name__ == '__main__':
jenkins_url = 'https://dev.localhost.com/XXXX/jenkins/'
server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, 'user', 'password')
jobs = server.get_jobs()
for job in jobs:
    print(job)
```

Comment: I tried the code mentioned above.  But stack trace is as follows.  It points to correct job but wrong URL

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='6.4.2.182', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /scm/jenkins /job/DONOTCHANTHISPROJECT/api/python (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5bcf894150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Comment: That feels like a separate issue. Can you post the full stack trace in the question above (or in a new one).